# how to use regular expression in EJB named query

Tags: java, orm, jpa

I have query in mysql like

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MOBILE) FROM TBLM_CUSTOMER WHERE MOBILE NOT REGEXP '^00*0$' AND LENGTH(MOBILE) >= 10;

I am using EJB 3.0 and I want to make same query using NamedQuery, same thing is possible using createQuery , but i want to use NamedQuery.

Is it possible to use regular expression using NamedQuery in EJB 3.0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.MOBILE) FROM Customer WHERE o.MOBILE != '^00*0$' AND LENGTH(o.MOBILE) >= 10;

where Customer is our entity bean , query work's fine as nativequery in EJB

Comment: `o.MOBILE != '^00*0$'`  .. ugh? no regexp?

Comment: ^00*0$ I wrote this because i want all the digit in the mobile can't contain zero.

Comment: This is mysql simple query --- SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MOBILE) FROM TBLM_CUSTOMER WHERE MOBILE NOT REGEXP '^00*0$' AND LENGTH(MOBILE) >= 10;

Comment: And this query in EJB give same result -- SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.MOBILE) FROM Customer WHERE o.MOBILE != '^00*0$' AND LENGTH(o.MOBILE) >= 10; -- I tested this with other regular expression of mysql also

Answer (score 2):

First of all, REGEXP is not a standard JPQL function defined by JPA but is platform-specific SQL. If it works with your current JPA provider (some of them might pass platform-specific SQL in the WHERE clause directly to the database, some of them might support extending a given dialect), portability isn't guaranteed (if this matters).

That being said, if you made it work using `createQuery(String)`, there is no reason it wouldn't work with a `NamedQuery`. Did you try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MOBILE) FROM TBLM_CUSTOMER WHERE MOBILE NOT REGEXP :regexp AND LENGTH(MOBILE) >= :length;
```

PS: Maybe it's just an example but why don't you use a `[NOT] LIKE` to keep your queries portable?

Comment: Does regular expressions work with LIKE option in jpql?